# CSS color mapping

Tags: html, css

Is that possible to map a color to a color name like below:

> light blue = #FF8000

The orginal color for this hex value #FF8000 is light orange

I need to map this value #FF8000 to light blue

Comment: why don't you just do a find and replace?

Comment: Are you designing an interface that isn't meant for human eyes? Why do you want to distort color associations like this?

Comment: I also don't think this is possible

Comment: Maybe Can you tell me how that can be done

Comment: did you convert the RGB colorspace to BRG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No it's not possible. The html-colornames are bound to a fixed Hex-value as defined in the [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/). The browsers automatically convert keywords like `lightblue` to this specific Hex-value (or RGB but that doesn't matter). You cannot change this behaviour.

Although you could use your own color-words like `lightBlue` and parse the stylesheets via javascript and apply the colors according to your own definitions.

Alternatively you can work with variables in SASS/LESS if that's what you want.

And btw, Simple question: WHY?

Answer (score 4):

Not with CSS by default, although this is coming. The proposed CSS Variables spec is at http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/ . Chrome have an implementation but it’s not turned on by default and is currently not in any released version.

You could use a preprocessor like SASS to do this for you. More info at http://sass-lang.com/#variables

Answer (score 1):

There is no reasonable way to do this (as in you probably don't want to).

The current color maps are in the HTML and CSS specification, that browsers adopt from. Being such, they can't be changed without some hacky way.

If you absolutely had to, you could do what was suggested and run a find/replace.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a class in css and set color (or background-color, whichever you want) to hex value and then use that class, otherwise I wouldn't know what you are wanting with this...

```
.lightblue
{
    color: #FF8000;
}
```